# How to cutoff strings around root string

Tags: python, pandas

How to cutoff strings around root string in csv file? Any Pandas solution?
I have my root strings in sentence in another column.

For example i have:

```
lack of association between the promoter polymorphism of the mtnr1a gene and adolescent idiopathic scoliosis
```

my root string: mtnr1a and i want have output:

```
promoter polymorphism of the mtnr1a gene and adolescent idiopathic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the sentence into a list of words, then finding the index of root string should do the stuff:

```
sentence = "lack of association between the promoter polymorphism of the mtnr1a gene and adolescent idiopathic scoliosis"
root = "mtnr1a"

try:
    words = sentence.split()
    n = words.index(root)
    cutoff = ' '.join(words[n-4:n+5])
except ValueError:
    cutoff = None

print(cutoff)
```

Result:

```
promoter polymorphism of the mtnr1a gene and adolescent idiopathic
```

Note: You need to catch `ValueError` when root string is not found in the sentence. In that case, `cutoff` is set to `None`

Comment: but how to do on pandas dataframe?

Comment: Do you want to cutoff all strings in col1 by all root strings in col2, or simply cutoff string at (col1,row1) by root at (col2,row1) and so on for other rows?

Comment: I want to cutoff all strings in col2(sentences) by root strings in col1 in each rows (i have more than 9 milion rows)

Comment: simply transform the code into a function and use `DataFrame.apply`. See [apply doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for more complete explanation

Comment: if I use this code:

sentence = data[sentence']
root = data['rootword']

def cutOff(sentence,root):


    try:
        words = sentence.str.split()
        n = words.index(root)
        cutoff = ' '.join(words[n-4:n+5])
    except ValueError:
        cutoff = None
    return cutoff


data.apply(cutOff(sentence,root),axis=1)

I get error: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable in n = words.index(root)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the 4 words on either side of the first occurrence of your "root string", you can use:

```
root = 'mtnr1a'
s = 'lack of association between the promoter polymorphism of the mtnr1a gene and adolescent idiopathic scoliosis'
s_list = s.split(' ')
ix = s_list.index(root)

out = ' '.join(s_list[-4+ix:ix+5])
out
# returns:
'promoter polymorphism of the mtnr1a gene and adolescent idiopathic'
```

Comment: but how to do on pandas dataframe?